# I want to Transfer some of my data from WHM server to SoftLayer Object Storage without using FTP or SCP, can any one suggest the way out?

Tags: object, storage, whm, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have tried this, but it is just adding the file to the object storage..

$ curl -i -XPUT -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkb26239d441d6401d9482b004d45f7259" --data-binary "Created for testing REST client" https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/v1/AUTH_df0de35c-d00a-40aa-b697-2b7f1b9331a6/container2/folder3/file1.txt

Answer (score 2):

The swift client is an easy way to list/upload/download files on SoftLayer Object storage.

https://swiftstack.com/docs/integration/python-swiftclient.html